# Why is my Iron Farm not working?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

A little while ago, I tried making an iron farm on my Xbox One Minecraft World, but I noticed, even in my village, when the villagers get spooked or even hit by zombies or such they don't spawn iron golems, which I thought they did. Is that mechanic only for Java Edition or am I somehow doing something wrong?

I used the design from this video:

Answer (score -1):

Sorry to say but this farm works for Java Edition only!
But this one workes for Bedrock! [Bedrock Iron Farm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3BhlLIIpRh4)

Comment: This answer isn't valid because it won't be able to stand on its own if the link were to somehow become invalid. Explain in detail why the farm in the question will not work in Bedrock Edition, and show what the video you linked does better, and that will make this a valid answer. I'm leaving this answer standing for now, but it is in dire need for improvement.

Comment: Yeah, but why??

Comment: @aytimothy I don't vote to delete bad answers immediately because I believe the user should have at least a week to improve the post. Let's make it easier for them by keeping the post alive for them to work off of, rather than starting from scratch. However, it's been almost a month without improvement and there has been no response, so it's safe to assume that they've abandoned this, so *only now* we can delete it. I don't have enough rep to delete vote, but I believe you do, so please do so if you'd like.